# Need to setup a profile which gets Flyway to clean the database on re-start

Tags: spring-boot, flyway

I want to start with a clean database when I run my spring boot application with a profile used for integration tests. The application is running in its own JVM and the integration tests are running in another JVM. It appears that adding:

```
spring.flyway.clean-disabled=false
```

to the integration properties file should do the trick, but it does not work.
The documentation says that the default setting for `spring.flyway.clean-disabled` is `false`, which implies if I don't set `spring.flyway.clean-disabled` in any of my properties files, then every time I start my application, I should get an empty database. But that is not true. The contents of the database are persisted between starts of the application.
So what needs to be done to start the application with a clean database? I'm using Spring Boot 2.3.1.RELEASE.

Answer (score 1):

> The documentation says that the default setting for `spring.flyway.clean-disabled` is `false`, which implies if I don't set `spring.flyway.clean-disabled` in any of my properties files, then every time I start my application, I should get an empty database.

No, you shouldn't get an empty database every time you start your application. Flyway is a database-migration tool. It would be rather awkward if it would *by default* completely wipe your database on every application start.

In contrast to the [migrate](https://flywaydb.org/documentation/command/migrate) command (which is automatically invoked by Spring Boot on application startup), [clean](https://flywaydb.org/documentation/command/clean) is a command that is helpful mainly during development and testing. You have to explicitly invoke it (for example via [Maven](https://flywaydb.org/documentation/usage/maven/clean) / [Gradle](https://flywaydb.org/documentation/usage/gradle/clean)).

The [cleanDisabled](https://flywaydb.org/documentation/configuration/parameters/cleanDisabled) parameter is just a safeguard that can be configured to prevent the `clean` command from being executed in a production environment.

Comment: I want to run my application in intellij so I can debug it while running the integration tests and I want to start with a clean database each time I run it. Setting -DFLYWAY_CLEAN_DISABLED=false on the program arguments or setting FLYWAY_CLEAN_DISABLED=false in the environment does not work. Is there any other way to do it without using maven/gradle?